# heatmap based on ratios in Python's seaborn

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, data-visualization, heatmap, seaborn

I have data in Cartesian coordinates. To each Cartesian coordinate there is also binary variable. I wan to make a heatmap, where in each polygon (hexagon/rectangle,etc.) the color strength is the ratio of number of occurrences where the boolean is True out of the total occurrences in that polygon.

The data can for example look like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,False],[-1,5,True], [51,52,False]])
```

I know that `seaborn` can generate heatmaps via [seaborn.heatmap](http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html), but the color strength is based by default on the total occurrences in each polygon, not the above ratio. Is there perhaps another plotting tool that would be more suitable?

Comment: the link is not functional (404)

Comment: Have you looked at: http://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.hist2d.html  (Sorry, couldn't edit the old comment anymore)

Comment: yes that looks like what I am looking for, but when I run it I get an error: `ImportError: cannot import name 'PercentFormatter'`. Maybe it is because I am using python 3?

Comment: Generally matplotlib works with Python 3. Have you tried the example in the docs? In any case, that sounds like a different question.

Comment: There is no boolean variable in the dataframe, so it's unclear how the data looks like.

Comment: Pardon @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, I added it. But the idea is there: in each polygon compute the ratio of how many are true out of the total in that polygon and base the heat map on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use the pandas `groupby` functionality to compute the ratios and then pass the result to seaborn.heatmap. With the example data borrowed from @ImportanceOfBeingErnest it would look like this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

np.random.seed(0)
x = np.random.poisson(5, size=200)
y = np.random.poisson(7, size=200)
z = np.random.choice([True, False], size=200, p=[0.3, 0.7])

df = pd.DataFrame({"x" : x, "y" : y, "z":z})
res = df.groupby(['y','x'])['z'].mean().unstack()

ax = sns.heatmap(res)
ax.axis('equal')
ax.invert_yaxis()
```

[the resulting plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VdXFr.png)

If your `x` and `y` values aren't integers you can cut them into the desired number of categories for grouping:

```
bins = 10
res = df.groupby([pd.cut(df.y, bins),pd.cut(df.x,bins)])['z'].mean().unstack()
```

Comment: Thanks @Gereleth, that's a very nice approach, I prefer using seaborn. May I ask perhaps: can this also be achieved using `seaborn.jointplot()`?

Comment: I don't think so, at least not easily. jointplot is for plotting bivariate relationships and I don't see a place for the third variable there. If you want to have distributions of `x` and `y` to the sides of the heatmap you can tinker with subplots manually.

Answer (score 1):

An option would be to calculate two histograms, one for the complete dataframe, and one for the dataframe filtered for the True values. Then dividing the latter by the former gives the ratio, you're after.

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.random.poisson(5, size=200)
y = np.random.poisson(7, size=200)
z = np.random.choice([True, False], size=200, p=[0.3, 0.7])

df = pd.DataFrame({"x" : x, "y" : y, "z":z})
dftrue = df[df["z"] == True]

bins = np.arange(0,22)
hist, xbins, ybins = np.histogram2d(df.x, df.y, bins=bins)
histtrue, _ ,__ = np.histogram2d(dftrue.x, dftrue.y, bins=bins)

plt.imshow(histtrue/hist, cmap=plt.cm.Reds)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

[image]