# Changing the axis of a seaborn heatmap

Tags: python, matplotlib, heatmap, seaborn

I have a set of Cartesian coordinates pairs, along with a binary variable for each of the pairs. I am plotting a heatmap, where in each bin, I compute the fraction of coordinates falling into this bin where the binary variable is 1.

My problem is with the axis. As can be seen in the picture below, the resulting axis are strings, that stand for bin boundaries. I would like the axis to  be Cartesian coordinates. Is there a simple way to change this?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sb
np.random.seed(0)
x = np.random.uniform(0,100, size=200)
y = np.random.uniform(0,100, size=200)
z = np.random.choice([True, False], size=200, p=[0.3, 0.7])
df = pd.DataFrame({"x" : x, "y" : y, "z":z})
binsx = 8
binsy = 5
res = df.groupby([pd.cut(df.y, binsy),pd.cut(df.x,binsx)])['z'].mean().unstack()
ax = sb.heatmap(res)
ax.axis('equal')
ax.invert_yaxis()
```

[image]

Comment: In [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42947766/4124317) to your last question you already have cartesian coordinates. Can you go more into detail what the final result should be like? Do you want to simply change the ticklabels? Or the axis scales?

Comment: Thank you, indeed it is the same application. I would like to change the axis scales, not only the ticklabels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following creates a scale by using the bins for histogramming as the extents of the image.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(0)
x = np.random.uniform(0,100, size=200)
y = np.random.uniform(0,100, size=200)
z = np.random.choice([True, False], size=200, p=[0.3, 0.7])
df = pd.DataFrame({"x" : x, "y" : y, "z":z})
binsx = np.arange(0,112.5,12.5)
binsy = np.arange(0,120,20)
res = df.groupby([pd.cut(df.y, binsy),pd.cut(df.x,binsx)])['z'].mean().unstack()

plt.imshow(res, cmap=plt.cm.Reds, 
           extent=[binsx.min(), binsx.max(),binsy.min(),binsy.max()])
plt.xticks(binsx)
plt.yticks(binsy)
plt.colorbar()
plt.grid(False)


plt.show()
```

[image]